# Can't seem to upgrade Windows 10 - Error 0x8007000d

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I've been struggling for a while with this - I've tried every article I could find.  Just can't get Windows to update :(

When I use Windows Update, I get:  Error Code 0x800700d

When I created a Windows 10 CD (Windows 10 May 2021 update):  It takes a very long time and then just pops a box that said Installation Failed.

When I run SFC /scannow:  Windows did not find any integrity violations

I have run all from the Administrator user (which is pretty much a new profile as I have my own domain account on the box).

When I run DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth:  I get Error: 87. The cleanup-image is unknown

I don't even know what else to do at this point :(

Comment: Have you run chkdsk against your drive?

Comment: What build are you currently running? Why are you trying to upgrade a machine connected to an AD domain?

Comment: I ran sfc /scannow, not chkdsk.  dong that now.  It is my own AD domain, what is wrong with upgrading the machine?  It has always self-upgraded before.

Comment: scan found no problems.

Comment: And also - since I'm the Administrator, I logged in locally to upgrade and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth: I get Error:
> 87. The cleanup-image is unknown

That is the correct command ( DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth  )

Also that is not good news that it will not run. I have used DISM numerous times.

At this point, then, you should do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Begin with the option to Keep Everything.  This usually works. The
> other two options ( Keep only Data (keeps your user profile but you must reinstall software) and Keep Nothing (everything is gone including your user profile) ) are more
> aggressive.  Of course, you must back everything up first.

Push comes to shove and you can try a bigger drive and set up that way or try dual boot and transition that way.

But reinstall (the Keep Nothing option) is the only real overall option left.

Comment: That command looks pretty similar to mine.  But - I tried it.  Same issue.

I also used the Media Creation Tool - created an ISO, ran it, that is what gives me "installation error" after about 2 hours.  I can certainly try again, but my steps were exactly like you said "keep everything"

Comment: If you try again and Keep Everything does not work, try Keep Data.  Data should not cause any issue. You will have to reinstall software. If Keep Data fails, then move to Keep Nothing. Be sure you have a complete data backup. Keep Data keeps your user profile and Keep Nothing deletes your user profile.

Comment: Well, the first test with that failed (keep everything).  As with the first time, I get the message:  "Windows 10 installation has failed".  Just a popup that only says this.

Comment: I think at this point you should ensure your data and documents and email are very completely backed up and then use the Keep Nothing option.  That is basically starting again.

Comment: If I were to do that, I would be better off running a dual-boot of some sort, I think.  I say this because this is my work machine.  It has to be updated (requirement), but I also have all of my work on it.  I use a lot of applications, so would be somewhat of a nightmare.  Which is why I am working hard to just upgrade it.

Comment: The operating system looks to be in bad shape.  No kind of upgrade has worked. I do not see how dual boot would help because on the new system you would still have install software.

Comment: @Andrew - Why are you handling the update yourself instead of your AD Administrator? I am hesitant to provide an alternative to that DISM command since this machine is connected to a domain and I have no information on what group policies might be applied to it

Comment: That it is a work machine is new since the original question earlier.

Comment: I use the machine for work. It is my machine and my local domain.  I'm in control of it, I'm the admin, I'm the domain admin ;)  I have a localized network including SAN, 2 EXSI servers, and tons of VMs.

Comment: And the dual-boot idea means that I still can use my old OS until everything is ported over.  That was the only thought there.

Comment: Your options see limited to me. You can get a new disk and set it up knowing that everything is on the other drive. If you get a big enough drive you can copy the old drive to the new drive and start setting it up. I am quite sure you will not fix the update problem short of the steps I laid out (and have used). I set up  a new Windows 11 desktop and it took about 2 days total. The old Windows 10 machine is in the basement. Dual boot is another option

Comment: That is much like my most recent comment and will work.